# Python crashed when I try to import Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook

When I import Tensorflow, Python crashes with the following output:

> C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:516:
>   FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is
>   deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as
>   (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.   _np_qint8 = np.dtype([("qint8", np.int8,
>   1)])
>   C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:517:
>   FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is
>   deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as
>   (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.   _np_quint8 = np.dtype([("quint8",
>   np.uint8, 1)])
>   C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:518:
>   FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is
>   deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as
>   (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.   _np_qint16 = np.dtype([("qint16",
>   np.int16, 1)])
>   C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:519:
>   FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is
>   deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as
>   (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.   _np_quint16 = np.dtype([("quint16",
>   np.uint16, 1)])
>   C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:520:
>   FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is
>   deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as
>   (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.   _np_qint32 = np.dtype([("qint32",
>   np.int32, 1)])
>   C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:525:
>   FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is
>   deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as
>   (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.   np_resource = np.dtype([("resource",
>   np.ubyte, 1)])

Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

*FutureWarning*= a warning about a future (not currently existing) version of numpy. As tensorflow will definitely address this warning when numpy updates,  you can ignore this. It's only a warning, I also get this warning, you can ignore it.

Comment: But i can't import tensorflow  when i try it python crashes?

Comment: the error you posted is not the cause of the crash then. What is the full output when you do `>>> import tensorflow` ?

Answer (score 0):

i solved my problem :

don't try uptade , uninstall tensorflow (i tried everything)

delete (if u use anaconda ) anaconda  and install again , mark "add Python to my PATH" during installation.

have a nice day.